# What happens if you die in A Dark Room?

Tags: a-dark-room

I had some good stuff on me and ran out of water. Is there a loot bag I can go pick up or is it lost forever?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You lose everything you were carrying when you die and they are forever lost, this includes the items you picked up and the ones you started with.

Permanent items (Upgrades) will not be lost, like: Waterskin, Rucksack and other items that increase water reserves, carrying capacity and increase health.

Also you will be kicked back to the village.

As you explore you will discover areas of the map. Going back to the village successfully makes these areas remain visible for the next travels, however, if you die, the last areas will be covered up again.

`Credits to fbueckert`

Comment: All of the items you took with you.  You don't lose the stuff in your settlement.

Comment: So if I cleared a city, I'll not only lose the loot from it, but also have to clear it out again? Do I also have to scout it out again on the map?

Comment: @scienceguyz Yes to both. Be careful out there!